# Handlebars chart input text issue

Tags: apache-superset

I have added text field and dropdown to the superset handlebars chart, but the controls are not allowing to type text in the text field. What could be the reason and how to fix it. Please see the handlebars template below

```
<ul class="data-table">
  <div class="controls">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="css-1inivuc">
          <label class="css-6bztgs">Name</label>
          <span class="ant-input-prefix">
         <input placeholder="Type a value" name="Name" type="text" class="ant-input" value=""/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="css-1inivuc">
          <label class="css-6bztgs">Filer ID</label>
          <span class="ant-input-prefix">
         <input placeholder="Type a value" name="FilerID" type="text" class="ant-input" value=""/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="css-1inivuc">
          <label class="css-6bztgs">Type</label>
          <span class="ant-input-prefix">
         <select placeholder="Select Type" name="Type" class="ant-input">
        {{#each data}}
                  <option value="{{Type}}">{{Type}}</option>
                {{/each}}
             </select>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>FilerID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  {{#each data}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{FilerID}}</td>
    <td><a href="/superset/dashboard/11/?Name={{Name}}">{{Name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{City}}</td>
    <td>{{Type}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </table>
  </ul>
```